# Android HTC G7 without Google applications

Tags: google-apps

I recently got an Android HTC G7 phone which claims to be Android 2.2. But I do not see any Google applications installed (market, maps etc). Is there a way to install these libraries and get started?

Answer (score 1):

The G7 is not actually made by HTC, [it's a cheap knockoff](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=801208).  I don't believe it actually runs Android.

Answer (score 1):

There is no phone from HTC named G7, the HTC G7 Desire is in fact a clone of the HTC Desire phone which runs Windows phone 6.5.

**How to identify a Desire clone:**

- Dual SIM
- Run Windows instead of Android.
- The rear speaker is on the left side
  of the camera.
- The 3.5 jack connector is on the
  bottom of the phone side by side with
  USB connector.

**Real Desire:**

- Single SIM
- Runs Android
- The rear speaker is on the right side
  of the camera, just like the flash.
- The 3.5 jack connector is on the top
  of the phone (top right corner)

[This is a video of the clone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgwPcmOcgvo).